# Jekyll _posts not found

Tags: jekyll

I've followed the steps for creating a _post entry in Jekyll. But it keeps saying page not found.

This works fine:
http://localhost:4000/blog/2015-12-31-Test

This does not:
http://localhost:4000/_posts/2015-01-01-test

I've searched around and haven't found anyone else with this issue.

---

Update 1:
I've also check the _sites folder and the post does technically get built, so the problem is the Jekyll server is failing to locate it after it builds it.

Additional info as requested:
1) Steps followed was from the official documentation here:
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/

2) I haven't yet tried uploading it to github to see if it works there as wanted to fix it locally first, however I will do and update this post if that fixes it:

Update2: I have now uploaded but found the same issue:
Source file:
    https://github.com/BadrulAlom/badrulalom.github.io/tree/master/_posts

Result (none of these work):
    https://badrulalom.github.io/2015-01-01-test
    https://badrulalom.github.io/_posts/2015-01-01-test
    https://badrulalom.github.io/_site/2015-01-01-test
    https://badrulalom.github.io/_site/_posts/2015-01-01-test

3) The _posts folder (I wrote _post in my initial question) is in the root not within the blog folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folders starting with an underscore are special for Jekyll, they won't be available in the URL as `/_foobar`, the special folder `_posts` is where all your posts should go if you don't use any other directory to contain them.

In this case you have the same post in the folder `_posts` and the folder `blog`, you should have only one instance of it to avoid any unexpected behaviour.

The default date permalink is defined according to the format `/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title.html` so that post should be available in the following *urls*:

- `http://localhost:4000/blog/2015/12/31/Test.html` loading the `/blog/_posts/2015-12-31-test.md` post.
- `http://localhost:4000/2015/12/31/Test` loading the `/_post/2015-12-31-test.md` post.

Comment: Thanks. The 'blog' was just as a test to prove the markdown was correct.

Comment: Using the path you suggested does work so thanks.

If that's the right answer then I'll have to suggest to the Jekyll folks that they update their user guide as it's not the least bit clear in their documentation (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/).

But it also leaves me a little bit baffled as to what is the value that Jekyll brings when they tout their _post functionality. From what I can see I'm better off ignoring _post and creating my own 'blog' folder.

Comment: Have a look at [permalinks](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/), it should carify things, cheers

Comment: Thanks. I've shifted my question over to the official Jekyll forum (https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/why-use--posts-over-a-non-special-folder/3465) as I'm not understanding why go to all that trouble of using permalinks when you can just avoid using _posts altogether. I suspect the answer is in a multi user environment rather than having lots of people posting to new sub-folders, everyone just submits to one folder and you use permalinks to create a virtual fixed path instead. If that's the case than as a newbie one-man band, I'm tempted to stick to just 'hard-wiring it' under 'blogs'.